# strtok() seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

I have already looked at other questions etc and i've seen you can't have a first arg in strtok that can't be edited but I don't think i have in this code but still getting a seg fault??
Am i using strtok wrong?

This code is to take stdin in csv comma delimited format and add the digits from the stdin then print them to stdout, p.s. i had it working when token wasn't a pointer eg. `i+= token;` but i was getting random output as would be expected i suppose.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char *token, input[256];
int i = 0;

scanf("%s" , input);
token = strtok (input, ",");

while(token != NULL){
    token = strtok(NULL, ","); 
    i += *token;

        }                

printf("%d\n", i);
return 0;
    }
```

Thanks Lachlan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At some point `strtok` will return `NULL` which you won't check:

```
token = strtok(NULL, ","); 
i += *token; /* Will dereference NULL. */
```

Instead you should be doing:

```
while(token != NULL){
    i += *token; /* We know `token` isn't NULL. */
    token = strtok(NULL, ","); 
}
```

As a side note what you are doing - adding character values - makes very little sense. You'll want to somehow convert them, probably using `strto(u)l`.

Comment: Doh! Thanks sorry about that.

Comment: pardon my ignorance i didn't find it in my research does `strtol(token)` change token to `NULL`?

Comment: @LachlanMcGivern `strtol` doesn't change its first argument.

Comment: but my `scanf"%s", input` won't work will it because it adds a null to the end of the string?? that what scanf man says anyway is that the same as `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string to integer before doing `i+=*token`, take a look at the function such as  `strtol` which convert a string to an integer.